# PowerShell use regular expression to split a string

Tags: regex, powershell, split

This is my code:

```
[regex]::split("1,2   3", '(,|\s)+')
```

What I want is an array with three elements `1, 2, 3`, however, what I got it is an array with five elements.

```
PS C:\Users\a> [regex]::split("1,2   3", '(,|\s)+').Length
5
PS C:\Users\a>
```

How to get what I want?

## Update

Add the actual `split` result instead of the `length`.

```
PS E:\> [regex]::split("1,2   3", '(,|\s)+')
1
,
2

3
PS E:\> [regex]::split("1,2   3", '(,|\s)+').length
5
PS E:\> [regex]::split("1,2   3", '[,\s]+')
1
2
3
PS E:\> [regex]::split("1,2   3", '[,\s]+').length
3
PS E:\>
```

## Update

Thanks @Matt's answer and it points me to the right direction. From `help about_split` the doc states that:

> By default, the delimiter is omitted from the results. To preserve all
>   or part of the delimiter, enclose in parentheses the part that you
>   want to preserve.

Below are some of my testing.

```
PS E:\tutorial>     "Lastname/:/FirstName/:/Address" -split "/(:)/"
Lastname
:
FirstName
:
Address
PS E:\tutorial>     "Lastname/:/FirstName/:/Address" -split "/:/"
Lastname
FirstName
Address
PS E:\tutorial>     "Lastname/:/FirstName/:/Address" -split "(/:/)"
Lastname
/:/
FirstName
/:/
Address
PS E:\tutorial>     "Lastname/:/FirstName/:/Address" -split "/:(/)"
Lastname
/
FirstName
/
Address
PS E:\tutorial>     "Lastname/:/FirstName/:/Address" -split "(/):(/)"
Lastname
/
/
FirstName
/
/
Address
PS E:\tutorial>     "Lastname/:/FirstName/:/Address" -split "(/)(:)(/)"
Lastname
/
:
/
FirstName
/
:
/
Address
PS E:\tutorial> [regex]::split("Lastname/:/FirstName/:/Address", '/(:)/')
Lastname
:
FirstName
:
Address
PS E:\tutorial> [regex]::split("Lastname/:/FirstName/:/Address", '/:/')
Lastname
FirstName
Address
PS E:\tutorial> [regex]::split("Lastname/:/FirstName/:/Address", '/:(/)')
Lastname
/
FirstName
/
Address
PS E:\tutorial> [regex]::split("Lastname/:/FirstName/:/Address", '(/):(/)')
Lastname
/
/
FirstName
/
/
Address
PS E:\tutorial> [regex]::split("Lastname/:/FirstName/:/Address", '(/)(:)(/)')
Lastname
/
:
/
FirstName
/
:
/
Address
PS E:\tutorial>
```

Comment: I've no knowledge of Powershell, but in many languages using a group in the regex means that the delimiters will end up in the list (it would be interesting to see the contents of the list). Does `[,\s]+` work?

Comment: Use ```[regex]::split("1,2   3", ",|\s+")```.

Comment: @Phylogenesis That changes the meaning of the regex, though, from one or more commas or spaces to either a comma or one or more spaces.

Comment: @Biffen Thank you for your answer. Yes `[,\s]+` works. But I'm not pretty sure why. I think I may have some knowledge gap in regex and I'll try to investigate.

Comment: @OgrishMan I don't think it's so much a regex thing as how `split()` works. As I said; in many languages the existence of a capturing group makes a difference. Could you show us the actual results of the `split()` (and not just the length)?

Comment: @Biffen I've added the actual `split` result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In PowerShell when you use a `-split` function if you have part of the match in brackets `()` you are asking for that match to be returned as well. I am sure that the same is true with the static method of `[regex]` as well. Consider the output from the two following commands (which are similar to yours) and you will see

```
[regex]::split("1,2   3", '(,|\s+)')

1
,
2

3

[regex]::split("1,2   3", ',|\s+')

1
2
3
```

In the first example you see that the comma and whitespace have been returned as elements. What I am explaining is documented in [About_Split](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847811.aspx)

> By default, the delimiter is omitted from the results. To preserve all
>   or 
>           part of the delimiter, enclose in parentheses the part that you want to 
>           preserve.

**In this particular case**

As pointed out in the comments there are 2 more ideal regex strings that would handle this particular case better

`(?:,|\s)+` or `[,\s]+`

Former using a non capturing group and latter being a character class.

Comment: Note that those regexen are quite different from OP's (although for this particular input the results happen to be the same). It should be either `(?:,|\s)+` or `[,\s]+`.

Comment: `,+|\s+` is *not* equivalent to `(,|\s)+` (and I'm not talking about the capturing group). The latter will match a mix of whitespace and commas but the former will only match a sequence of one or the other.

Comment: @Biffen. Yes you are right. I reverted the edit. Leaving it be proves the point. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Note that `,|\s+` isn't equivalent to `(,|\s)+` either.

Comment: @Biffen That I am aware of. The comment in the answer _(which are similar to yours)_ was an attempt to cover for that. Giventhe example he gave it is the query I would use. split on comma or a group of whitespace. I appreciate your diligence.

Answer (score 2):

I might be late to the party but below example works for me.

```
"Lastname,FirstName, Address pincode" -split "[\s,]+"
Lastname
FirstName
Address
pincode
```